# How to apply specific function to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been trying to apply functions based on multiple columns.
[image]

I have two columns that have polygon datatype. Using these columns I would like to create an "intersection" column which is calculated by

```
(df["roi_coors"].intersection(df["coors"]).area / df["roi_coors"].area) * 100
```

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
df['intersection'] = (df["roi_coors"].intersection(df["coors"]).area / df["roi_coors"].area) * 100
```

Note: I am not sure how to handle a polygon datatype so this answer is based on the fact that the calculation function is correct

Comment: yes, I have tried and I got the error smth like: Series does not have intersection attribute ...

Comment: Oh, based on that error, I think that creating an 'intersection' column is not the problem, rather your use of .intersection() which I cannot really help with.

Comment: individual cell has polygon type which should be ok, if I apply function